# Как передать переменную в модальное окно pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Есть форма, которая строит таблицу из некоторых данных. У каждой строки в таблице есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую открывается модальное окно. Мне надо передать в него переменную, которая соответствует этой строке.

Само

```
script(src='/js/adminpanel/feedbackModal.js')
#myModal.modal(userId)
form(action = "/feedback/", method = "POST")
    .modal-dialog
        .modal-content
            .modal-header
             .modal-body
                 .form-group
                    label(for="userId" name='userId' value="test") text  #{userId}
                    .row
                        input(type="text" name="userId" value="")
                        button(type="submit") End
```

JS скрипт для него, который может получать переменную

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
const formUserId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('userid');
});
```

Код самой кнопки

```
button.btn.btn-sm.btn-block.btn-outline-secondary.back-button(type='button' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-userId="test value") info
```

Вопрос, как мне получать это значение в модальном окне?

UPD: В Js пытался добавить следующий код, но результата это не принесло

```
    $(e.currentTarget).find('userId').val(formUserId);
```

Comment: `pug` не динамический, как он отрендерится в начале - такой и будет на готовом `html`. Ваш вопрос решается с помощью `js`

Comment: а именно при открытии модального окна берете значение строки и вставляете куда надо в модальное окно